# Is my solution for .webp format in html correct?

Tags: html, webp

In web I found this variant:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/img/test.webp" type="image/webp"/>
  <source srcset="/img/test.jpg" type="image/jpeg"/>
  <img src="/img/test.jpg" alt="test"/>
</picture>
```

but I also try my variant:

```
<img srcset="/img/test.webp, /img/test.jpg" src="/img/test.jpg" alt="test"/>
```

they both works well in google chrome, because currentSrc property of img in both is "/img.test.webp".

But what proc and cons of each variants in my case?

I prefer variant with `img` and `srcset` attributes because it require less code.

PS: I can't simply use `src` attribute for `img` tag with path to .`webp` image, because not all modern browsers support .`webp`.

Comment: Well [srcset isn't support by IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset)

Comment: for IE i set src attribute

Comment: Why don't you just use src everywhere? What's the point in maintaining two code bases for the same thing. Also browser detection doesn't work well

Comment: I need to user webp in browsers that supports it. src attribute used for backward compatibility for old browsers/ie. Not all modern browser supports webp format

Comment: This is a bit of a hack – you’re relying on `srcset` support to mean WebP support. If that’s true in practice for the browsers you’re targeting, it’s fine, but it won’t extend to any other new image formats while they’re fresh.